# ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler does not redirect to login page

Tags: spring-security

I have configured an ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler like this:

```
@Bean(name = { "defaultAuthenticationFailureHandler", "authenticationFailureHandler" })
protected AuthenticationFailureHandler defaultAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
    Map<String, String> exceptionMappings = new HashMap<>();
    exceptionMappings.put(InternalAuthenticationServiceException.class.getCanonicalName(), "/login?error=servererror");
    exceptionMappings.put(BadCredentialsException.class.getCanonicalName(), "/login?error=authfailed");
    exceptionMappings.put(CredentialsExpiredException.class.getCanonicalName(), "/login?error=credentialsExpired");
    exceptionMappings.put(LockedException.class.getCanonicalName(), "/login?error=locked");
    exceptionMappings.put(DisabledException.class.getCanonicalName(), "/login?error=disabled");
    exceptionMappings.put(AccessDeniedException.class.getCanonicalName(), "/login?error=denied");

    final ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler result = new ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    result.setExceptionMappings(exceptionMappings);
    result.setDefaultFailureUrl("/login?error=default");
    return result;
}
```

I also have a custom AuthenticationProvider which throws an InternalAuthenticationServiceException or BadCredentialsException depending on the error. So now I go to login page and try to login with invalid username/password. I start debugging it and I can see it goes in ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler where it redirects to the correct URL, but then the flow goes to ExceptionTranslationFilter line 168 where an handles an AccessDeniedException (don't know why it was raised) and the ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler  is called again but this time it redirects to "/login" so in the end I am redirected to "/login" instead of "/login?error=authfailed"

Comment: It sounds as thought he redirect is working but the URL you are redirecting to is not marked as permitAll. Try ensuring that the URLs for handling errors are marked as permitAll.

Comment: Hi Rob, I debugged it and it seems that `ExceptionTranslationFilter` line 168 (the second time) the request URL is again `/login?error=servererror` so it seems this URL is not allowed. But how can this be, I have:

                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .loginPage("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/console")
                .failureHandler(defaultAuthenticationFailureHandler())
                .permitAll()


so if I open /login I can see the login page. If I manually go to /login?error=servererror I am redirected to /login.

Comment: formLogin().permitAll() requires the query string to be an exact match (in this case it would be /login?error). Therefore you need to use authorizeRequests().antMatcher("/login").permitAll() to ensure access is granted.

Comment: Hi Rob, it worked! However I still believe there's a bug in ExceptionMappingAuthenticationFailureHandler on line 36 - because this FailureHandler extends the SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler you can set a useForward property, on line 36 we are missing an if statement to check if the user selected to forward or redirect. Once again thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Rob pointed out **formLogin().permitAll() requires the query string to be an exact match (in this case it would be /login?error). Therefore you need to use authorizeRequests().antMatcher("/login").permitAll() to ensure access is granted**